# Aggregate date and time in R

Tags: r, date, time, time-series, aggregate

My data has a start and end time stamp such as this:

```
200401010000 200401010030
200401010030 200401010100
200401010100 200401010130 and so on...
```

I'm trying to convert these fields into %YYYY%MM%DD%HH%MM format using lubridate and as.POSIXct but it I get only NAs. Any help will be appreciated.
My goal is to aggregate the data for each month. 
The code I've used so far is as follows:

```
start_time = as.POSIXct(dat$TIMESTAMP_START, format = "%YYYY%MM%DD %HH%MM",origin = "2004-01-01 00:00", tz="EDT")
stop_time = as.POSIXct(dat$TIMESTAMP_END, format = "%YYYY%MM%DD%HH%MM",origin = "2004-01-01 00:30", tz="EDT")
dat$interval <- interval(start_time, stop_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems I can see:

1. If you're using `lubridate` already, you should probably use the function `ymd_hm()`, which is just cleaner IMO.
2. You can't apply that function to a vector (which I presume `dat$TIMESTAMP_START` and `dat$TIMESTAMP_END` are); to do this, you can use:

   ```
   start_time <- sapply(dat$TIMESTAMP_START, ymd_hm())
   end_time <- sapply(dat$TIMESTAMP_END, ymd_hm())
   ```

   That will apply the function to each item in your vector.